# Setting the origin of a C# panel control, or moving its contained controls programmatically

Tags: c#, panel

So, I have a simple task (so I thought) - I have a panel control which contains a label control.

I have directional control buttons, and movement buttons.  The movement buttons should move the location of the label control in either x or y direction depending on which movement button is selected. The selected direction is stored as a property of the Class.

All of these functions are working, except this: when I instantiate the Robot class, the pointer should be on the center of the screen. This needs to be the origin. However, by clicking the Move 10 button, the pointer moves to 0,10 (x,y) starting from the top left corner position.

Since I need the center to be the origin, I tried moving the control's 0,0 point to where I want it, but that makes any negative values (from the controls top left) invisible, which can not work.

[image]

I am hoping someone can explain to me how to fix this. Oh, while I am at it, why isnt the panel's border showing?

A Robot object is created from the class when the form loads. The directional and movement code is like this:

```
        private void btnGoTen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (isValidDirection())
            if (robot.Direction == "N")
                robot.Y -= 10;
        if (robot.Direction == "E")
            robot.X -= 10;
        if (robot.Direction == "S")
            robot.Y += 10;
        if (robot.Direction == "W")
            robot.X += 10;
        lblPosition.Text = robot.GetFormattedLocation();
        lblRobotLoc.Location = new Point(robot.X, robot.Y);
    }

    private void btnNorth_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        robot.Direction = "N";
    }

    private void btnEast_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        robot.Direction = "E";
    }

    private void btnSouth_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        robot.Direction = "S";
    }

    private void btnWest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        robot.Direction = "W";
    }
```

And the class itself is simple enough, as follows:

```
    public class Robot
{
    //fields
    private int x;
    private int y;
    private string direction;

    public Robot()
    {
        x = 0;
        y = 0;
        direction = "N";
    }


    public int X
    {
        get { return x; }
        set { x = value; }
    }

    public int Y
    {
        get { return y; }
        set { y = value; }
    }

    public string Direction
    {
        get { return direction; }
        set { direction = value; }
    }

    public string GetFormattedLocation()
    {
        string locationString = "{X=" + Convert.ToString(x) + ",Y=" + Convert.ToString(y) + "}";
        return locationString;
    }
```

Comment: You'll need to include some code, and where you think it may be going wrong.

Comment: Code added. However, since I can't move the label to those negative positions, I don't have a clue where its going wrong.

Comment: This mountain has to come to Muhammad.  lblRobotLoc.Location = new Point(panel1.ClientSize.Width / 2 + robot.X, panel1.ClientSize.Height / 2 + robot.Y);  Bounds checking needs to be added.

Comment: If you're attempting to do a Cartesian coordinate system where 0, 0 is the center, you're going to have to some magic as 0, 0 in the panel is the top left corner (as it is with all other controls.

Comment: @krillgar thats what I couldn't solve.. I went with the solution from Hans, and it worked well